# Trouble using preceding-sibling on tokenize result loop

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to use XSLT to parse a flat text file into XML.  A single "record" of my resulting XML file might encompass more than one line of my text file:

```
12345 Bob 100.00
12345 Bob 50.00
34567 Joe 20.00
```

What I want to do is only right out the identifier once and then create unique amount elements for each line of the text file:

```
<record>
  <person>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <id>12345</id>
  </person>
  <amounts>
    <amount>100.00</amount>
    <amount>50.00</amount>
  </amounts>
</record>
<record>
  <person>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <id>34567</id>
  </person>
  <amounts>
    <amount>20.00</amount>
  </amounts>
</record>
```

Normally I take my input file and tokenize on the line break, loop through and write out each record

```
<xsl:variable name="src" select="unparsed-text($inputfile,'UTF-8')" />
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($src, '&#10;')" >
```

And I was hoping I could do the ol' compare a `$previousId` variable to the current line's parsed out ID, if they were different write my `person` info, otherwise just write the `amount` records. And at the end update the `$previousId` with the current ID.  But XSLT variables can't be updated.

After that I thought maybe I could use something like `select="preceding-sibling::.[1]"` but that complains because tokenize apparently isn't returning nodes, but a type of `xs:string`.

So is there a way I can iterate over the results of a tokenized string, but somehow compare against the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `preceding-sibling` axis here is that the items in the tokenized sequence are - just that, a sequence and they are neither siblings of each other nor do they have aparent.

> So is there a way I can iterate over the results of a tokenized
>   string, but somehow compare against the previous line?

Yes there are ways to do this. Note: You do not show much of your XSLT code, so I have to assume it to some extent.

---

But you could make the variable a sequence of tokenized strings:

```
<xsl:variable name="src" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($inputfile,'UTF-8'),'&#10;')" />
```

Then, you can refer to an item in the variable via its index, for example `$src[1]` gives you the first line.

Further, if inside a `for-each` loop, you could then refer to the preceding line

```
<xsl:for-each select="$src">
  <xsl:if test="string-length(.) le string-length($src[position() -1])">
    <!--More code-->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Above, `.` is the current line, `$src[position() -1])` is the one immediately preceding it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That worked exactly how I was looking to do it.  I had some weirdness where `$src[position() -1]` wouldn't work, it kept returning an empty string or null or something...my element just kept being empty. I ended up creating a new variable, `<xsl:variable name="lineToGet" select="position()-1" />`, and then referencing that `$src[$lineToGet]` and it worked like a dream.  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way of looking at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="inputfile"/>
<xsl:key name="record" match="record" use="field[1]" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="records">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text($inputfile,'UTF-8'), '&#10;')" >
            <record>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')" >
                    <field>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </field>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <!-- output -->
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($records/record/field[1])" >
            <record>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="." /></id>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="key('record', ., $records)[1]/field[2]" /></name>
                <amounts>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('record', ., $records)" >
                        <amount><xsl:value-of select="field[3]" /></amount>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </amounts>
            </record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```